# Using the join function on python to format a dictionaary

Tags: python

I am trying to format a dictionary where the key is the name of predators in a food web and the value is a list of preys that the predator eats. I am able to get the whole print out but the list of preys that are printed out are all seperated by commas. I want to format it so the last comma is not a comma but say the word "and".

This is what I have, d is my dictionary:

```
for key in d:
        print(key, "eats", ', '.join(map(str,d[key])))
```

This prints out, for example:

```
Lobster eats mussels, limpets, whelk
```

I would like to replace the last comma with "and". I know I have to find the index for the comma and that is done by:

```
pos=str(d[key]).rfind(",")
```

I just don't know how to finish it from here.

Any suggestions?

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

In your example you may have a problem if `prey` contains a comma, is that possible?

I would suggest:

```
for predator, prey in d.items():
    print '%s eats %s and %s' % (predator, ', '.join(prey[:-1]), prey[-1])
```

`for predator, prey in d.items()` loops over all key and value pairs.

`', '.join(prey[:-1])` takes all but the last prey and joins them with comma's

`prey[-1]` then adds the last prey

Each `%s` is replaced by the values in the tuple at the end of the line

Comment: This is the nicest solution but you're missing a closing bracket after `prey[:-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
def add_and(s):                                
   before, after = s.rsplit(', ', 1)
   return before + ', and ' + after

>>> add_and('Lobster eats mussels, limpets, whelk')
'Lobster eats mussels, limpets, and whelk'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for key in d:
  l = d[key]
  print ', '.join(l[:-1]) + ' and ' + str(l[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use this in case `len(preys) <= 1`:

```
for predator, preys in d.items():
    print '{0} eats {1}'.format(  predator,
                                  ', '.join(preys[:-1]) + \
                                  " and " + preys[-1] if len(preys) > 1 else preys[-1],
                                  )
```

Comment: @user1883020 nice :) please support my cause by upvoting and/or selecting my answer